# Why people choose to buy Arduino when they can get a cheaper and better dev board?

Tags: arduino, development-tools

Why people choose to buy Arduino when they can get a cheaper and better dev board?

For example, Arduino Uno with ATmega328 has only 16Mhz clock speed, 32KB Flash and 16 IOs costing 20£.

Where as for 10£ you can get STM32F4 DISCOVERY with 32bit ARM Cortex-M4 having 168Mhz clock, 1MB Flash and 100 IOs?

Comment: Because of the software tools and user community associated with Arduino. But this isn't an EE question, so it will be closed.

Comment: @DaveTweed: It's not a shopping question. It is a EE question. He want's to know whether there's an issue or something he's missing that he should know about the difference between the two systems. It shouldn't be closed since others might benefit.

Comment: Absolutely the ease of use due to the whole Arduino ecosystem (hardware, software, users, projects, visibility, entry level programming, ...)

Comment: "Cheaper" and "better" are subjective terms which do not mesh well with the Q and A format of this site. There can be no authoritative answer to these sorts of questions.

Comment: Comparing an 8 bit AVR board to a 32 bit ARM board is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: So questions on "Why" isn't a EE question? Isn't development of standards and understanding of EE trends also part of EE?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: I never said it was a shopping question. But it's definitely "not constructive" under the EE guidelines. It could also be construed as spam.

Comment: This is the definition of not constructive.

Comment: Note that the STM32F4 unfortunately does not come with source for the libraries for the on-board peripherals - there's source for the libraries handling the on-chip peripherals, but things like the microphone supplied on the board work in the demonstration firmware by use of closed-source support libraries provided only for some compilers.

Comment: I don't think this is apples and oranges. The ARM board is more powerful and cheaper, hands down. The Arduino board is expensive because it is popular. People use Arduino without even evaluating alternatives like this just because Arduino is a buzzword they have heard often. This creates demand, and demand exerts an upward pressure on pricing.

Answer (score 4):

To put it in a simple comparison, The Arduino and the culture around it is like Legos, made to fit together easily and simple. Pre-made modular system with little work needed on the user's end. A Lego tower is easy to build.

The Discovery board on the other hand, is like real construction equipment. A real building tower is not so easy to build.

Most people are likely to go with the simple option, even if it cost more. Same reason people buy premade computers, when making your own is cheaper and better.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer boils down to the customer.

If you're a hobbyist trying to get a project together, then Arduino includes many example projects and a lot of tutorials on how to get things running. Programming it is a breeze because of the IDE. The integration job is amazing and it makes it easy for entry level.

The STM32F4 is an excellent board that in some ways might appeal to hobbyists because of the price, but in reality ST is trying to get at TI (which I believe popularized the inexpensive Launchpad or EZ430 board first). When ST is trying to find new customers, it's very cheap and easy to introduce them to the microcontrollers with this board. The customers are likely somewhat sophisticated at the use of microcontrollers and know that at some point they'll move to a dev board or their own design. When customers are looking for a microcontroller, ease of use is not first on their mind (though it sometimes should be). They're usually willing to deal with different toolchains, new configurations, etc because in the end it's a higher performance part with more capabilities and at a low price in quantities. The ease of use and community don't figure that much into the equation.